# One of these two operators is not invertible

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a Hilbert space $H$ and a bounded self-adjoint operator $T$ on it with $||T||=1$. I've been trying to show that at least one of $I+T, I-T$ are not invertible, but I haven't been able to make any progress yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Berrick The answer below looks great, but unfortunately I'm not knowledgable enough to understand it (I'm learning about the basics of adjoints, and know nothing about spectral radii). One tool that I do have, which I've been trying to apply, is the following fact: a self-adjoint operator $T$ is invertible iff there exists $\delta$ such that $\langle T^2x,x\rangle\ge \delta||x||^2$.

Comment: Hi graviola. Let me think about it.

Comment: Hi graviola. Are you aware of the fact that for a self-adjoint $ T \in B(\mathcal{H}) $, we have
$$
   \| T \|_{B(\mathcal{H})}
= \sup(\{
   |\langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}| \mid
   h \in \mathcal{H} ~ \text{and} ~ \| h \|_{\mathcal{H}} = 1
   \})?
$$

Comment: Offhand this looks like like one of those cases where the hypothesis $\dim H>0$ is missing.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: That’s true.

Comment: @Berrick Yes, I know this fact, and your second answer is perfect for my background, thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: If $\mathrm{dim}H = 0$, there is no operator with norm $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another answer that is suitable for the poster’s background. We make use of the fact that for a self-adjoint bounded operator $ T $ on a Hilbert space $ \mathcal{H} $, we have
$$
  \| T \|_{B(\mathcal{H})}
= \sup(\{
  |\langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}| \mid h \in \mathbb{S}(\mathcal{H})
  \}),
$$
where $ \mathbb{S}(\mathcal{H}) $ denotes the unit sphere of $ \mathcal{H} $.

Suppose that $ \| T \|_{B(\mathcal{H})} = 1 $. Then there is a sequence $ (h_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ \mathbb{S}(\mathcal{H}) $ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} |\langle T(h_{n}),h_{n} \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}| = 1.
$$
As $ T $ is self-adjoint, we have
$$
\forall h \in \mathcal{H}: \quad
  \langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}
= \langle h,T(h) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}
= \overline{\langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}},
$$
which means that $ \langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \in \mathbb{R} $ for any $ h \in \mathcal{H} $. Hence, we can find a subsequence $ (h_{n_{k}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ of $ (h_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ such that either

1. $ \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle T(h_{n_{k}}),h_{n_{k}} \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = 1 $, or
2. $ \displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \langle T(h_{n_{k}}),h_{n_{k}} \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = -1 $.

Suppose that Case (1) occurs. Observe that
\begin{align}
\forall h \in \mathcal{H}: \quad
       \left\langle {(T - I)^{2}}(h),h \right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}
& =    \langle (T - I)(h),(T - I)(h) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\
& =    \langle T(h),T(h) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} +
       \langle h,h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} -
       \langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} -
       \langle h,T(h) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\
& =    \langle T(h),T(h) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} +
       \langle h,h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} -
       2 \langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \qquad (\text{As $ T = T^{*} $.}) \\
& =    \| T(h) \|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} + \| h \|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} -
       2 \langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \\
& \leq \| h \|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} + \| h \|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} -
       2 \langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \qquad
       (\text{As $ \| T \|_{B(\mathcal{H})} = 1 $.}) \\
& =    2 \| h \|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} - 2 \langle T(h),h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}.
\end{align}
As
\begin{align}
    \lim_{k \to \infty}
    \left(
    2 \| h_{n_{k}} \|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} -
    2 \langle T(h_{n_{k}}),h_{n_{k}} \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}
    \right)
& = \lim_{k \to \infty}
    (2 - 2 \langle T(h_{n_{k}}),h_{n_{k}} \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}) \qquad
    (\text{As $ h_{n_{k}} \in \mathbb{S}(\mathcal{H}) $.}) \\
& = 2 - 2(1) \qquad (\text{By the assumption of Case (1).}) \\
& = 0,
\end{align}
it follows from the Squeeze Theorem that
$$
  \lim_{k \to \infty}
  \left\langle {(T - I)^{2}}(h_{n_{k}}),h_{n_{k}} \right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}
= 0.
$$
Hence, there **cannot** exist a $ \delta > 0 $ such that $ \left\langle {(T - I)^{2}}(h),h \right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \geq \delta \| h \|_{\mathcal{H}}^{2} $ for all $ h \in \mathcal{H} $, which immediately implies that $ T - I $ is not invertible.

If Case (2) occurs, then by a similar argument, $ T + I $ is not invertible.

Answer (score 4):

As $ T $ is bounded and self-adjoint with norm $ 1 $, its spectrum $ \sigma(T) $ is a compact subset of $ [-1,1] $, and its spectral radius $ r(T) $ equals $ 1 $. Hence, either $ -1 \in \sigma(T) $ or $ 1 \in \sigma(T) $.

- If $ -1 \in \sigma(T) $, then $ 0 \in \sigma(I + T) $, and so $ I + T $ is not invertible.
- If $ 1 \in \sigma(T) $, then $ 0 \in \sigma(I - T) $, and so $ I - T $ is not invertible.